# Out of scope CGFloat array

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, cgfloat

I want to use a C-style `CGFloat` array defined in the `didMoveToView` method in the `touchesBegan` method. I can't seem to define it as a property because it is a `CGFloat` array. Globals don't seem to work either. My array is defined like this:

```
CGFloat levelMapX[] = {self.frame.size.width/2 ...};
```

I am using SpriteKit.

Comment: What about an instance variable?

Comment: That should compile. Post the entire method.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a pointer to a `CGFloat`. Although arrays and pointers [are not the same in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641963/2128900), they can often be used in a similar way.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat* array;
```

And then use it like an array:

```
const NSInteger myArraySize = 10 * sizeof(CGFloat);
self.array = malloc(myArraySize);
self.array[0] = 0.42;
self.array[1] = M_PI;
```

remember to free it so you don't leak memory:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    free(self.array);
}
```

Comment: freeing it made the app crash, I'm not sure why

Comment: The code should actually read `const NSInteger myArraySize = 10 * sizeof(CGFloat);`, where 10 is the number of `CGFloat`s. `malloc` uses size which are in bytes.

Comment: @RedBadger how did you initialize `self.array`? I tested it and `free` didn't crash.